# Creating Two-Dimensional Array in java & index pos

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, initialization

I already know that how to initialize two dimensional array.
But I don't figure out it why.For ex:

I think the initialization should be :

```
int [][]b=new int[][5];
```

instead of

```
int [][]b=new int[5][];
```

based on following reasons:

assume int[] ==Class A

```
  A b[]=new A[5];
```

when I replace A with int [],the outcome is

```
 (int[])b=new (int[])[5];
```

So where I miss the point?
Thanks a lot .

Comment: You missed the fact that `new int[M][N]` means "a length-M array of length-N arrays", not vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two-dimensional array in Java is just an array of arrays. It's easier to understand if we visualise the first-level array as holding the *rows* of a matrix, and the second-level array as holding the columns *in each row* - this makes sense, because when we access an element in position `m[i][j]` we're referring to the row `i` and the column `j`. When we write this:

```
int[][] b = new int[5][];
```

… We're stating that the array will have 5 rows, but we don't know in advance how many columns will have each row (this number can be variable!). On the other hand, when we say this:

```
int[][] b = new int[5][5];
```

… We're stating from the beginning that there will be 5 rows, each one with 5 columns. Now you can see why this doesn't make sense:

```
int[][] b = new int[][5];
```

… It'd be like saying: we want to have 5 columns, but we don't know how many rows there will be - and remember, a two-dimensional array is an array of *rows*, where each row contains another array representing the columns in that row.

Comment: Suggest finding a better term than "rows" - that implies a direction (i.e. rows vs. columns), which is not the case.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm appealing to an intuitive notion for the explanation, I can't think of another word without resorting to a direction

Comment: How about "outer" and "inner"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it's less clear IMHO. I'm sticking with "rows" and "columns", but adding a clarification at the beginning that this is just a way to visualise what's happening.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez thanks for making the idea clear for me.